# Bootstrap 3 Datepicker - enabledHours() expects an array parameter

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, datepicker, bootstrap-datetimepicker

I am using Bootstrap 3 Datepicker on a page with 2 timepickers - when I use them together I get an error:

> `enabledHours()` expects an array parameter

If I run just one then I don't get any error.

Here is the code I am using for the picker:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function () {
    $('.datetimepicker1').datetimepicker({
        showClose: true,
        format: "HHmm",
        enabledHours: [14, 15, 16, 17, 18],
        sideBySide: true
    });
});
```

I have created a fiddle which recreates this at https://jsfiddle.net/zgyd1qqd/1/

Additionally, I also did a fiddle with the same code (https://jsfiddle.net/zgyd1qqd/2/) but with only one picker initialized and the error is not present so, I assume, the format etc of `enabledHours` is actually OK?

Is there something else wrong in my code?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's probably because the array is referenced by both datepickers.

You could avoid this by iterating over each of the elements you are initializing the datepicker on:

[**Updated Example**](https://jsfiddle.net/dnb2ajc8/)

```
$('.datetimepicker').each(function () {
    $(this).datetimepicker({
        showClose: true,
        format: "HHmm",
        enabledHours: [14, 15, 16, 17, 18],
        sideBySide: true
    });
});
```